# MongoDB aggregation: concatenation strings in pipeline

Tags: python, mongodb

I am new to MongoDB and faced an issue. In my aggregation pipeline I have such data structure:

```
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "letter": "b"
  },
  {
    "_id": 2,
    "letter": "b"
  },
  {
    "_id": 3,
    "letter": "a"
  }
]
```

I desire to merge all of these items by `letter` property in order to have `"bba"` string in the end (so basically just a concatenation of those letters).

I did try reading about `mergeObjects` which failed because `string is not an object` as well as reading about other possible approaches. It just looks like I'm missing something here.

Is there a possibility to return such result and maybe somebody can help me to understand how?

Thanks a lot in advance and have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

So after looking into it for a while I've come up with an answer to such problem. In aggregation pipeline I added:

```
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      letters: {
        $push: "$letter"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      _id: null,
      letters: {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": "$letters",
          "initialValue": "",
          "in": {
            "$concat": [
              "$$value",
              "$$this"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
```